# Schedule SSRS task

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to schedule two reports, one report to be triggered on the last working day of the month. Another report to be triggered on the first workday of the each month. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  SSRS have a built-in subscription mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean by "triggered"?

Comment: @DStanley - The built-in subscription mechanism can't manage first and last working days of the month.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin No, but you could create two subscriptions per month and specify the dates.  Not saying it's great, but you can do it without custom development.

Comment: @DStanley - Yes, obviously you can also export the report manually and send it to the recipients. I definitely prefer spending some time to automate a process rather than wasting time every month to do repetitive tasks. But I admit that if you were my colleague and you proposed to create those 2 subscriptions per month (+ additional subscriptions requested from time to time), I wouldn't refuse :-)

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Like I said, it's not great, but it works out-of-the-box.  Depending on how much control you have of your SSRS environment it may be a lot less work than developing an app to run on a custom schedule.

Comment: @DStanley - We agree on that point

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no ways to do this through the standard subscription mechanism.

Your requirements are not only conflicting with the UI (the ReportServer website), but with the Reporting Services database design. You can take a look at the `Schedules` table to see what I mean.

There are 3 things you could do:

1. *Fast & Risky, not recommended*
   Edit the generated SQL job (**never tested and not supported**), here you can specify weekdays.
   [image: Schedule]
2. *Good approach but (very) long term*
   Submit a [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) suggestion.
3. *Recommended but needs development*
   Develop an application that consume the Reporting Services webservice and has a tailored subscription mechanism.

You could consider doing step 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

a subscription on the first day of the month is pretty easy.  Whether data driven or static the schedule you set up can be set to run on the first day of every month.
[image]

For the last day of every month, you'll need to create 3 subscriptions.  One subscription for **September, April, June and November** (on calendar day(s) = 30), one for **all the rest** (on calendar day(s) = 31), and one **for February alone** (on calendar day(s) = 28).

Leap years.... you're on your own there...

Comment: The OP said the first and the last *working* day of the month